# How to make the HTML (component) of jaspers auto - height..?

Tags: html, jasper-reports

I have a code in jrxml like.

```
 <detail>
        <band height="35">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="38" y="12" width="457" height=<![CDATA[$P{col1_Header}]]> isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" />
                <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="RetainShape" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Middle">
                    <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA[com.turborep.turbotracker.util.ReportUtils.toHtml($F{InlineNote})]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
                </hc:html>
            </componentElement>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="292" y="2" width="65" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" />
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="33" y="2" width="64" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" />
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="357" y="2" width="74" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" />
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="94" y="2" width="71" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" />
            </rectangle>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="43" y="2" width="128" height="20" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Product}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="173" y="2" width="100" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ItemQuantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="273" y="3" width="134" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Paragraph}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="407" y="3" width="103" height="20" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{Price} == null) ? "" : "$"+$F{Price}.setScale(2, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="16" y="0" width="23" height="20" />
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}+"."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

[image]
[image]

where my html content will grow bigger, so i want the html component to have auto height or it should support overflow. Now it is shrinking the size of the components as it grows.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Hi alex, Please look at the two images above. In the first image there is only one line which i have added into report through the html component of jasper. But when the no of lines increases the size of letters are decreasing or shrinked.

Comment: Is there any way to display html content in Jasper?

Comment: @Kannan_SJD how did you resolved?